# Using python 3.8 but importing pytest from 2.8 instead of 3.8

Tags: python, pytest, version

I'm using python 3.8 but pytest keeps getting imported from 2.7
These are my commands:

```
python3.8 -m venv venv
. ./venv/bin/activate
pip3.8 install --upgrade pip
pip3.8 install -U pytest
pip3.8 install -r requirements.txt
```

Then I check:

```
(venv) xxx@xxx:~/Documents/my-dashboard$ pytest --version
This is pytest version 3.3.2, imported from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytest.pyc
```

Why is pytest imported from 2.7 version if my environment is using 3.8?
How do I import pytest from 3.8?

Comment: Probably need to use `pip3 install` or `pip3.8 install`.

Comment: Good idea. I tried but it didn't help. So all my commands were python3.8 and pip3.8 but pytest still gets imported from 2.7

Comment: Shouldn't you `source./venv/bin/activate`? Are you sure you are running `pip` commands IN the venv you created? Maybe run `which python` before them to be sure?

Comment: What helped was to purge python2.7 - but this isn't the solution I'm looking for as I'm running a venv and should be independent of all the python versions installed on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re installing with python3.8 and pip3.8 you should run with:

```bash
python3.8 -m pytest
```

Your default python on your path seems to be 2.7, so you need to change your PATH or be explicit about which python you want to run.